# Magento custom language file not being used

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I have created a custom language file for a feature that I have built into our Magento website. The language variables work fine on my local machine (of course), however on our staging environment it doesn't. My local machine is Windows and staging server is Linux, so obvious answer would be an issue with filename casing, but imho these are right.

I have my own block that overwrites the Mage_Catalog, called `Feno_Catalog` which works fine. To that config.xml file I've appended some code to load the `Feno_Catalog.csv`;

/local/Feno/Catalog/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Feno_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Feno_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <class>Feno_Catalog_Block</class>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <class>Feno_Catalog_Helper</class>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Feno_Catalog>
                    <files>
                        <default>Feno_Catalog.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Feno_Catalog>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Feno_Catalog>
                    <files>
                        <default>Feno_Catalog.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Feno_Catalog>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

The CSV file has been put into 2 folders: `/app/locale/[de_DE|en_US]/` with matching casing.

As I mentioned it works fine on my local machine, but not on the staging server. What could cause this? I've searched for quite a bit and cleared cache (although cache is turned off), switched languages (both languages don't work - The language keys are like "poll_question_a1").

When I move the translations to Mage_Catalog.csv everything also works fine (but of course that is not what I want).

So how to fix? Is there any way to find the cause of this?

Comment: By any chance you have developer mode enabled on your local machine or on the staging server?

Comment: Developer mode is currently disabled on both environments. I tried switching it on but it breaks on some other warning. Anything specific I need to look for?

Comment: I found this `if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
                            unset($this->_data[$key]);
                        }` in the translate model and I thought it might have something to do with it.

Comment: Unfortunately not, added a `die("in dev mode");` inside the statement, but no change.

Comment: This is a long shot, but have you tried removing `encoding="iso-8859-1"` from the `config.xml` file?

Comment: Nope, didn't work :-(

Comment: The weird thing is that it's now also been tested on another dev machine (Win) and it also works fine there. Not sure if the Win vs Linux is they cause.. Otherwise file permissions to the translation files are wide open.

Comment: As a suggestion I found somewhere else I added logging to Translate.php where `_loadModuleTranslation` is called and I found that the translation module is not loaded on the staging environment but it is on the staging environment. 
Have I forgotten something somewhere?

Comment: is the compiler active on the server?

Comment: I figured out this issue at a later stage, I had forgotten to add something to the config.xml file. We use GIT for version management and some XML files are excluded. So it worked locally, but forgot to push the change to the staging environment. n00b error